# How To Remove The Last Char Entered In a text box in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i am working on an assignment to make a scientific calculator in C# wpf and i have complete it except one thing that i have a backspace button on my ui but cant understand the logic that how to remove the last number entered in text box or calculator screen. 
anyone help me plz,
thnx in advance

Comment: Please add the stacktrace and code. You may also have a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the question. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is psuedocode, but you could take the number divided by 10. This will work for integers.

```
int x = 12345;
//x is the textbox value
x = x / 10;
```

If you're also using doubles perhaps cast it to a string, remove the length by one, then case it back to a double:

```
String s = substring(x.toString(), 0, x.toString().length - 1);
x = s.parseDouble();
```

Comment: i have done it using this code. 

String text = textBox.Text;
text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1);
textBox.Text = text;